# Send json object as body in a POST request

Tags: json, angular, csv, asp.net-web-api

I develop a project in Angular 9 which reads a csv file and send its content to the server.
I  have a model for the file's records.

The request shows the object in "Request payload" but when it get to the API conntroller the data doesn't recognized as [FromBody] parameter.

Do you have any solution for me?
This is my code:

Model:

```
export class CSVRecord {
public code: string;
public date: Date;
public value: number;
public period: string;
```

}

Type script:

```
    export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FastWayToSerieses-Client';

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService, private http: HttpClient ) {
}


  public records: any[] = [];
  @ViewChild('csvReader') csvReader: any;

  uploadListener($event: any): void {

    const text = [];
    const files = $event.srcElement.files;

    if (this.isValidCSVFile(files[0])) {

      const input = $event.target;
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
      console.log('after read as text');

      reader.onload = (e) => {
        console.log('onload');
        const csvData = reader.result;

        const temp = ( csvData as string).replace(/\r/g, '\n');
        const csvRecordsArray = ( temp as string).split(/\r\n|\n/);

        const headersRow = this.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray);
        this.records = this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray, headersRow.length);
        (document.getElementById('sendButton') as HTMLInputElement).disabled = false;

      };


    } else {
      alert('Please import valid .csv file.');
      this.fileReset();
    }
  }

  getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray: any, headerLength: any) {
    console.log('getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile');
    const csvArr = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < csvRecordsArray.length; i++) {
      const curruntRecord = (csvRecordsArray[i] as string).split(',');
      if (curruntRecord.length === headerLength) {
        const csvRecord: CSVRecord = new CSVRecord();
        csvRecord.code = curruntRecord[0].trim();
        csvRecord.date = new Date(curruntRecord[1].trim());
        csvRecord.value = Number(curruntRecord[2].trim());
        csvRecord.period = curruntRecord[3].trim();

        csvArr.push(csvRecord);
      }
    }
    return csvArr;
  }

  isValidCSVFile(file: any) {
    return file.name.endsWith('.csv');
  }
  getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArr: any) {
    console.log('getHeaderArray');

    const headers = (csvRecordsArr[0] as string).split(',');
    const headerArray = [];

    for (const header of headers){
      headerArray.push(header);
    }
    return headerArray;
  }

  fileReset() {
    this.csvReader.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.records = [];
  }
```

This is the function ehich dend the data to the server:

```
sendCSV(){
    console.log('click');

    const url = this.apiService.baseUrl + 'API/SeriesAPI/UploadSeriesData?option=1';

    // const body = JSON.stringify(this.records);

    this.http.post(url, this.records  ,
    {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
       'Content-Type':  'application/json;chrset=UTF-8'
      })
    }
    )
    .subscribe(x =>
      {
        console.log(x);

      });

  }
```

[Debugger chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cGeb.png)

Comment: chrset is not spelled correctly in your js. Can you show your controller code?